# Show/hide a table row based on nested class

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I have a button on a page that I want to only show rows that have a certain class (`target-class` in my example) within them. If you press the button again, then all rows are shown.

I'm not sure how to check if `target-class` is within `<tr class="show-hide-this-one">`

```
<button id="btn-toggle_target" type="button">Show Targets Only</button>
<table>
    <tbody>
    {% for item in first_list %}
        <tr class="show-hide-this-one">
            <td> {{ item.title }} </td>
            <td> 
                <table><tbody>
                {% for subitem in item.sublist %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            {{ subitem.value }}
                            {% if value == 0 %}
                                <span class="target-class"> Looking for this one </span>
                            {% endif %}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                 {% endfor %}
                 </tbody></table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function toggleTarget() {       
        $btnToggle = $("#btn-toggle_target")
        var showTargetOnly = $btnToggle.hasClass("target-only")
        if (showTargetOnly) {
            $btnToggle.html("Show Targets Only").removeClass("target-only");
            $().show();
        }
        else {
            $btnToggle.html("Show All Records").addClass("target-only");
            $().hide();
        }
    }

    (function () {
        $("#btn-toggle_target").on('click', function() {
            toggleTarget();
        });
    }());

</script>
```

Comment: could you show an example of html generated? its easier to use in snippet

Comment: @Frenchy here's a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/jd8hqz5e/

Comment: ok without id ou more classes, its little complex..

Answer (score 0):

it was not so easy because you dont have class or id but with a little loop its ok:

```js
$("#btn-toggle_target").on('click', function() {
            toggleTarget();
        });
        
     function toggleTarget() {       
        var showTargetOnly = $("#btn-toggle_target").hasClass("target-only");
        if (showTargetOnly) {
            $("#btn-toggle_target").html("Show Targets Only").removeClass("target-only");
            $(".show-hide-this-one table tr").show();
        }
        else {
            $("#btn-toggle_target").html("Show All Records").addClass("target-only");

            $(".show-hide-this-one table td").each(function(){
                if($(this).find(".target-class").length == 0) $(this).closest("tr").hide();
            })

            //this loop coul be replaced by
            //$(".show-hide-this-one table td:not(:has(.target-class))").closest("tr").hide();
        }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn-toggle_target" type="button">Show Targets Only</button>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="show-hide-this-one">
            <td> Item 1  </td>
            <td> 
                <table><tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            0
                            <span class="target-class"> Looking for this one </span>
                            
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            1
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            3
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                 </tbody></table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="show-hide-this-one">
            <td> Item 2 </td>
            <td> 
                <table><tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            4
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                 </tbody></table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

i think, you could replace this loop :

```
      $(".show-hide-this-one table td").each(function(){
        if($(this).find(".target-class").length == 0) $(this).closest("tr").hide();
      })
```

by

```
     $(".show-hide-this-one table td:not(:has(.target-class))").closest("tr").hide();
```